# Multiproccessing Pipe() Wrapper Broken: Something is Hanging. V5

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, multiprocessing, ipc, shared-memory

## Enhanced Python Multiprocessing Data Pipeline Wrapper

This is the goal...

## Objective

This is a piece of a big project I'm working on. This is an important part that will massively simplify report transmission in my program.  The program tests a function against millions of inputs and uses multiprocessing to speed thing up.  [Source code on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/iuRLdSqe).

## Goals and Benefit

Put simply, `multiprocessing.Pipe()` is inadequate.  It should be able to handle massive strings and switch process execution between a sender and receiver.  I wrote this to implement:

- Automatic error handling
- Transmission error categorization
- Data transmission chunking and reassembly
- Unlimited data transmission size
- Process synchronization
- Simple abstraction to enhance usability

## *Former* Problem

> It has a weird bug I can't find.  Days and plenty of documentation later, it's not fixed.  I've left in a good many debug lines.  Try entering "hi":  you don't see "Receiver.Test: Output: hi" but should.  Try a second time, it just hangs:  [Sample output](https://pastebin.com/cMRKc3eS).

Fixed by a dear friend.

## Tests

The GPE works.  Both of these first two tests work.  For test 1, this [source code](https://pastebin.com/6w2se8Sz) outputs [these results](https://pastebin.com/7F7fqzqj) correctly and consistently.  For test 2, this [source code](https://pastebin.com/MuM5fvAk) outputs something like [these results](https://pastebin.com/hwWzfa7R) correctly.  For test 3, this [source code](https://pastebin.com/vMwwL60e) outputs something like [these results](https://pastebin.com/a6ku2rGb) correctly.

## Plea!

> It's time to ask for help.  It is part of a larger project.  To be fair, there are a good many lines of code.  This should be part of the `multiprocessing` module.  I'm humbled.  Can someone tell me what up?  PLEASE?  ANYONE??

Nobody answered...

Comment: Your code is very difficult to follow—one liners with several branches of logic, as well as deeply nested functions (ie: `get_ps_id`). I'd imagine that almost any significant bug would be difficult to hunt down in this module. Consider breaking code out more and unit testing, you'll find your bug ,and in the end the module will have test coverage and be easier to maintain.

Comment: This observation likely has great creedence.  I just chunk my code in (admittingly) non-debugger friendly ways.  I hate atomizing code.  That's what C++ is for.  In Python, one line should be a sentence...  I guess I favor complex-compound sentences...  But, you're not wrong.

Comment: Did you already look at IPython Parallel? It allows you to do parallel computing with a much higher level interface and has a lot more features than `multiprocessing`. https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

In `receive_oscillate`, `yield from` looks like it never clears.

## Notes

Also, deeply nested functions and one liner compound conditionals are not idiosyncratic to Python. Furthermore, breaking up your deeply nested functions and adding automated unit tests will help reduce bugs and facilitate maintenance.

Comment: Yes.  If you send a keyboard interupt, you can figure out that the sender is hanging because the reciever won't process either of its inputs.